# Connection string not working when saving to 2007 format

Tags: interop, excel-2007, oledb, vb.net-2010, excel-2010

I'm very confused with OleDB & Excel.

I've 2 files:

```
One is saved in Excel 2007
One is saved in Excel 2010
```

This is because some computers have 2007 and other 2010 version of Microsoft Excel.

In vb.net i use:

```
 m_sConn1 = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';", file)
```

When is do:

```
conn1 = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(m_sConn1)
conn1.open()
```

With the save-in-2010 file i got 0 errors.
With the one saved in 2007 i got

```
"External table is not in the expected format"
```

Is this string connection for both versions? Should i use Interop instead? (because the file is auto generated using Interop Excel 12.0 and it works in 2007 & 2010).

I already installed 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Edit:

- If i open the 2007 file in 2010 and save it, oleDB reads it ok.

Comment: I know there are some questions asking the same, but all of them are about changing Jet for ACE. But my case is diferent, it won't work with files saved in 2007.

Comment: It's a Bug already reported. Only Excel 2007 has this error and MS knows it but never addressed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Bug already reported. Only Excel 2007 has this error and MS knows it but never addressed it.

This project can be only use w/ excel 2007.